# adding new values to existing object keys

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object with number values assigned to keys

```
obj1 = {a : 10
        b : 5
        c : 6 }
```

and I want to decrement each number to zero so that each key has all values in that range, i.e:

```
obj2 = {a : 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
        b : 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
        c : 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}
```

ive tried .map, .apply, and several other attempts at iteration. how can I accomplish this?

Comment: `obj2` is not valid. Each value must be an array, e.g. `a: [10, 9, 8, ...], b: [5, 4, 3, ...]`. In regards to the goal, you've mentioned that you have made multiple attempts; can you please share them? We'd much prefer to debug your existing code as opposed to writing it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of object entries, and then use `reduce()` to create the result object:

```js
const obj1 = {
  a: 10,
  b: 5,
  c: 6
};

const obj2 = Object.entries(obj1).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({
  ...a,
  [k]: Array(v + 1).fill(0).map(_ => v--)
}), {});

console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: Holy moly that's amazing. Thank you, that was driving me insane!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler solution:

```
const obj1 = { a: 5, b: 6, c: 3 };

let obj2;
Object.keys(obj1)
  .forEach((key) => {
    const size = obj1[key];
    obj2[key] = new Array(size + 1)
      .fill(0)
      .map((val, index) => size - index);
  });
console.log(obj2);
```

The result thus obtained will be in this format:

```
{
  a: [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  b: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  c: [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj1 = {
  a: 10,
  b: 5,
  c: 6,
};

let obj2 = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj1).map(([k, v]) => [k, [...Array(v)].map((_, i) => v - i)]));
console.log(obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj1 = {a : 10, b : 5, c : 6}

let res = Object.entries(obj1).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return Object.assign(acc, {[cur[0]]: Array.from(Array(cur[1]+1).keys()).reverse().join()})
}, {})
        
console.log(res)
```